# Using PHP array in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, google-pie-chart

I have an array in my PHP code (budgetingMain.php) called "totals". I want to use it for my data to create a Google Pie Chart. However, I am having difficulty in encoding it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var jsontotals = <?php echo json_encode($totals) ?>;

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Amount Spent on it');
        data.addRows([
          'jsontotals'
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chartcontainer'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

In this current setup, I get the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" for this line.

```
var jsontotals = <?php echo json_encode($totals) ?>;
```

I realise it's an issue with the embedding, but I cannot find a way to get it to work. Any help welcome!

**EDIT: This is the structure of totals**

```
$totals = array(
array("ClothingAndAccessories",0),
array("FlowersAndDecorations",0),
array("Ceremony",0),
array("Reception",0),
array("Photography",0),
array("Gifts/favours",0),
array("Stationary",0),
array("Entertainment",0),
array("Other",0)
);
```

Comment: Is this a .php page?

Comment: @James Yes, do I need to change the type?

Comment: No, you don't need to change the type. What is being echoed out to the browser? Are you seeing `var jsontotals = <?php echo json_encode($totals) ?>;` when you open your browser? If this is the case, then php is not parsing properly, and is likely an issue with your host.

Comment: @Danbopes  nothing is being echoed; just empty space

Comment: What is $totals being set to earlier in the script?

Comment: @Danbopes I've edited so you can see the structure of totals. To spare everybody reading through my php code, it basically recognises if an item in the table comes under one of the categories; if it does, it adds the cost of that item to the total cost (the number currently set as 0 in the array).